# How cloud computing sevices provide a virtual instance of dedicated server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, server, dedicated-server

I want to know that if I rent a dedicated server from cloud computing service like amazon web services, google cloud.

How can they provide me a server instance? Do they have physical dedicated servers for each one who is renting dedicated server from them or they create a virtual machine like Oracle Virtualbox or VMware?

Comment: A "dedicated server" has a specific meaning and it may not be what you assume. Please clarify what you mean when you say *"dedicated"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS supports 2 types of dedicated hardware.

The first is [dedicated hosts](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/). For this you will have a physical server, with information such as socket and core usage. In addition it allows you to benefit from licensing models whereby you pay by the core as oppose to paying for each VM individually.

The second is [dedicated instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-instance.html). This is similar to the above in that you will have dedicated physical hardware but you will not have visibility over it. Both dedicated and on-demand instances can live on this hardware, but only from your account.

Below is a comparison between the two.

[image]

These options become significantly expensive if you use only a small number of the available capacity.

Answer (score 1):

**GCP has also two ways os hosting your VM's;**

1. VM's are just hosted on the availability basis with other users' VM's. Just like VMware etc.
2. You can also choose [Sole-tenant nodes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/sole-tenant-nodes) which are

> physical Compute Engine server that is dedicated to hosting only your
> project's VMs

This feature will keep your VM's on this "private" node (starting from 60 cores & 240GB's of memory). This will increase your control over what is going on the machine and how the VM's will impact each-other's performance. This will also inmprove security (you rent your own hardware) and compatibility (RODO, Finance, Health care sometimes have their specific requirements).

Moreover

> Within a sole-tenant node, you can provision multiple VMs on machine
> types of various sizes, which lets you efficiently use the underlying
> resources of the dedicated host hardware.

But similarily as in AWS this is [quite pricey](https://cloud.google.com/compute/sole-tenant-pricing) because you rent entire node which start from over 1000 USD / month if you [commit](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts) for a 3 year sustained use:

[image]